# Qué significa :: en python?

Tags: python

¿Por qué al utilizar:

```py
Lista[:: -1]
```

En Python esto invierte la cadena, entonces qué significa `::`? . Una respuesta muy explicita y que explique bien los entresijos de lo que esto hace estaría muy bien...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Las listas y cadenas soportan el operador *slice*, cuya sintaxis general es `[inicio:fin:paso]`. Por ejemplo lista[3:20:4]. Esto causa que se extraiga la sublista compuesta por los elementos [3], [7], [11], [15] y [19]. De forma general, se comienza por el índice `inicio`, y se le va sumando `paso`. Cuando se llega a `fin` o mayor, ya no se extrae (`[fin]` nunca formará parte de la sublista extraída).

Los tres parámetros son opcionales:

- Si omites `paso`, se considera 1. Entonces `lista[3:20]` extraería todos los elementos entre 3 y 19, ambos inclusive.
- Si omites `inicio` se considera 0. Entonces `lista[:5]` extraería los elementos 0 a 4 ambos inclusive. O dicho de otra forma "los 5 primeros elementos".
- Si omites `fin`, se considera la longitud de la lista más 1. Es decir, `lista[5:]` te devolverá la sublista con los elementos 5, 6, etc.. hasta el último (inclusive).
- Si omites los tres, tienes la sintaxis `Lista[:]` que te devuelve una copia de la lista completa, pues inicio se considera 0, fin se considera el último elemento (inclusive) y paso se considera 1.

  Esta opción puede parecer tonta o inútil. ¿Por qué hacer `a = b[:]` pudiendo hacer `a = b`? La razón es que la segunda asignación no hace una copia, simplemente hace que `a` se *refiera* a la misma lista a la que se refería `b`, pero sólo existe una lista, con "dos nombres" por así decir. En cambio `a = b[:]` crea una copia de los elementos de `b` en una nueva lista, y `a` se refiere a la nueva lista. Son dos objetos diferentes. Equivale a `a = b.copy()`.

Por otro lado, el paso puede ser negativo, lo que implica que `inicio` debería ser mayor que `final`. Así por ejemplo `Lista[10:3:-2]` comenzaría por el índice 10 e iría descendiendo por 8, 6, 4, y ahí se detendría pues el siguiente (2) ya es menor o igual que `fin` (3).

En el caso en que paso sea negativo, entonces la omisión de de `inicio` y `fin` tiene significado ligeramente diferente. `inicio` se considerará igual a la longitud de la lista, y `fin` se considerará el primer elemento (inclusive).

Por tanto `Lista[::-1]` comienza por el último índice de la lista, retrocede de uno en uno y termina en el primero (0). Es decir, devuelve la misma lista pero "al revés".

Como ves `::` en sí no es un operador especial, es sólo que se han omitido `inicio` y `fin` de la sintaxis del *slice*. Es necesario dejar los huecos, pues si pusiéramos por ejemplo `Lista[-1]` o `Lista[:-1]` no quedaría claro que ese -1 se refiere al "paso", de ahí los dos `::`.

Comment: Buena respuesta, muchas gracias!!